# Conditional compilation if data type is different

Tags: c++, templates

I have some templates spezialized for certain data types. Now in the x64 build the types are different, so it works fine. For a x32 build, the datatypes are the same, so I wonder if I can do a conditional compile only if the datatypes are different.

```
template <> const usize_t NumericColumn<int_t>::MinDefault = (usize_t)INT_MIN;
template <> const usize_t NumericColumn<int_t>::MaxDefault = (usize_t)INT_MAX;
template <> const usize_t NumericColumn<uint_t>::MinDefault = (usize_t)0;
template <> const usize_t NumericColumn<uint_t>::MaxDefault = (usize_t)UINT_MAX;

// May not work in 32 bit build, but so far we don't need this anyway and if it is
// desired, it needs to be adjusted accordingly with an ifdef WIN32/WIN64
template <> const usize_t NumericColumn<ssize_t>::MinDefault = (usize_t)LLONG_MIN;
template <> const usize_t NumericColumn<ssize_t>::MaxDefault = (usize_t)LLONG_MAX;
template <> const usize_t NumericColumn<usize_t>::MinDefault = (usize_t)0;
template <> const usize_t NumericColumn<usize_t>::MaxDefault = (usize_t)ULLONG_MAX;
```

In x32 `usize_t` is `uint_t` is `int`, so I get a compiler error because the templates are instantiated twice.

I can of corse use a

```
#ifdef WIN64
    template usize_t...
#endif
```

But I was wondering if I can do this in C++ with comparing the type itself, which would be cleaner IMO. If I use a `static_assert` I can only generate an error, which of course is not what I need here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is already in the standard library:

```
template <typename T>
const usize_t NumericColumn<T>::MinDefault = std::numeric_limits<T>::min();
template <typename T>
const usize_t NumericColumn<T>::MaxDefault = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
```

---

As to the question you actually asked, you could use a compile-time program:

```
template <typename T>
const usize_t NumericColumn<T>::MinDefault = DefaultComputer<T>::min;
template <typename T>
const usize_t NumericColumn<T>::MaxDefault = DefaultComputer<T>::max;
```

and implement `DefaultComputer` as a metaprogram to do the calculation you want, e.g. by storing a list of type-value pairs and taking the first entry with a matching type.

A maybe better way is to do the specialization based on type names you know to be distinct; e.g. assuming you are using suitable types,

```
template <typename T>
const usize_t NumericColumn<int32_t>::MinDefault = INT32_MIN;
template <typename T>
const usize_t NumericColumn<uint32_t>::MinDefault = UINT32_MIN;
template <typename T>
const usize_t NumericColumn<int64_t>::MinDefault = INT64_MIN;
template <typename T>
const usize_t NumericColumn<uint64_t>::MinDefault = UINT64_MIN;
```

Comment: I tried using the `std::numeric_limits<T>::min()` approach, but for some reason it doesn't work on VS 2010 (even though I think its the correct approach). It gets confused with Windows min/max macro (which IMO is a compiler bug) but even when I remove it, I still get compiler errors refering to functions, so I assume that VS2010 doesn't have it yet. I ended up using basically the approach you mentioned at the bottom so I don't need ifdefs.

Comment: @Devolus try `(std::numeric_limits<T>::min)()`. Note extra parens. VS2010 definitely has `std::numeric_limits<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this:

```
enable_if<is_same<uint_t, usize_t>::value>
```

Comment: And how do you use it in OP's example ?